# Edit meta data of PDFs in iBooks.app?

Tags: macos, pdf, books, high-sierra

I use iBooks to store longer PDF's like scientific papers etc., so I can easily read them on my iPad.

But a lot of them do not have any meta data attached (like author) and/or have really bad file names.

I can't find a simple way to edit this within iBoks. What is the best possible solutions?

I guess I could export the PDF's, edit meta data in Adobe Acrobat Pro (or similar), and add them back. But I hope there is a simpler and quicker solution. Any suggestions?

Example below.

[image: bad file names]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after some trial and error, I found out how to do it.

When in **list view** you can just click the text fields and edit it. It's not that intuitive that the data only can be edited from one specific view, but glad there is an easy way to do it!

[image]

Comment: External links rot. Can you somehow include the picture(stream) to your solution?

Comment: Included it using the StackExchange Imgur image uploader, but bad quality because of 2mb limit.